# Having issues with floating divs

Tags: html, css-float

I've never had issues with floating divs before but something fishy seems to be going on with a current project I'm working on. For the life of me, I can't get the divs to float next to one another.

Here is the site: http://travel.tailwatersflyfishing.com
UN:admin
PW:admin

You will see two light grey divs labeled "FRESHWATER DESTINATIONS" & "SALTWATER DESTINATIONS", those are the divs I can't get to float next to eachother.

Ive been banging my head on the desk for two hours so I figured something is going on outside of my skillset??

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have this after each menu item

```
<div class="clear"></div><br>
```

Remove this and it works fine

Comment: Thanks for putting that out. That code was actually being spit out from the php file for the menu I'm using. 

Here is what was causing the clear class... 
return wp_nav_menu( $defaults ).'<div class="clear"></div>';

I removed <div class="clear"></div> but the <br> tag is still there... now causing the saltwater box to be shifted down a bit. 

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove : `"<div class="clear"></div><br>"` after your below `"div"` ends

```
<div class="menu-freshwater-destinations-container"></div>
```

and  in the change the `"float"` property of the class `"div.menu-saltwater-destinations-container"` in CSS to `"right"`.

All will work fine.